# CSS Reset Not Working with Firefox and Text

Tags: css, firefox, reset

I have been working on the Eric Meyer CSS Reset. I have a site that is text heavy. The reset works for the margins. But it hasn't been working for font and font size. Firefox seems to make all text smaller even though I have a reset in place. Is there any way to fix this in the CSS code?

Or are there any Firefox hacks that would work? If you want to see what my problem is load my page in chrome, and then load it in Firefox and compare: http://emilymagnuson.com/mynews/index.html

Also, I am a beginner, so if there is something I'm blatantly missing, please tell me. It would be so appreciated.

Thank you!

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
} 
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
   quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}


#box {
    background-color: #0F3;
    margin: 0px;
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #F00;
}
```

Comment: What happens if you **include** a font manually? Try a font from [Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts)

Comment: You can never expect to control text the way you can an image.  Every browser has a slightly different engine for rendering text (OS differences, rounding differences, font smoothing, font availability, etc.).  Even if text *was* rendered the same way, you cannot prevent users from overriding it to be something bigger or smaller or changing the font-face all together.

Comment: Yes, I understand this. But I'm working on a newspaper site and would like to find a way to control fonts in div containers. I already use google fonts, and that solves nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The mentioned `reset.css` isn't linked in [the site you've linked above](http://emilymagnuson.com/mynews/index.html)!

Additionally, this looks like a rounding error to me.

Your CSS rule:

```
.BodyType {
    font-size: 1.125em;
    line-height: 1.65em;
}
```

Firefox and Chromium both show `1.125em` for the font size, while Opera displays `1.13em` in Dragonfly.

Include the `reset.css` and test it with a complete test case. If there are still differences, try to limit the decimal places to two (e.g. `1.13em`).

If you set a pixel value for the font size on the `body`-element, try to use fractions that result in integer values. For example a base font size of `10px` and an element font size of `1.125em` will result in a computed font size of `11.25px`, whereas an element font size of `1.2em` will result in a computed font size of `12px`.

Comment: Thank you Feeela, but how do I link the reset? I didn't know there was something to link.

Comment: @Emily Magnuson If you want to use some stylesheet, you have to include it in your HTML, using `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="…" />` as usually. You've already done that for your own CSS file.

Comment: Thanks Feeela, but my above code is CSS so there shouldn't be any links in it.

Comment: @EmilyMagnuson I'm not talking about your CSS code. To cite myself from above answer: "the site you've linked above", which means http://emilymagnuson.com/mynews/index.html, which you would have seen by clicking the link…